# SQL match for 5 or less wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

I've got a variable which exists as a value in one of the columns, but I need to extract the column value only if the variable is at a specific position.

i.e after the first 5 characters, or maybe first 3 characters, but not more than 5.

If the value exists after 5, it should not be returned.

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Sample:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (
    name LIKE '_____$abc%'
    OR material LIKE '_____$abc%'
    OR material LIKE '____$abc%'
    OR material LIKE '___$abc%'
    OR material LIKE '__$abc%'
    OR material LIKE '_$abc%'
    OR material LIKE '_$abc%'
    OR material LIKE '$abc%'
)";
```

Is this the only way I can extract it?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CHARINDEX` for this. It gives you the first position of a string within another string. In the example below I've called the data I'm looking for `'string'`

Sample Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Name varchar(10), material varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #TestData (Name, material)
VALUES
('Aaron','asdfasdfstring')
,('Billy','asdfstring')
,('Clive','asstring')
,('Dave','asdffsdastring')
,('Eric','ddstring')
,('Frankie','stringasdfasdf')
```

Query;

```
SELECT 
Name
,material
FROM #TestData
WHERE CHARINDEX('string',material) <= 5
```

Result;

```
Name    material
Billy   asdfstring
Clive   asstring
Eric    ddstring
Frankie stringasdfasdf
```